# Jmeter Real time result in Non-GUI via Docker

Tags: docker, jmeter, influxdb

I have set up JMeter in Non-GUI mode in docker with influxdb and Grafana.
Jmeter real time results are first shipped in influxdb and shows on Grafana dashboard. Below is the table format which is being shipped in influxdb:

[image]

My team requirement is to see the **view result tree** result in Grafana as they want to see request/response for each transaction as per below:

[image]

Please help me to ship the result in influxdb of same as we team want to see each request/response in Grafana otherwise no use of dockerize the Jmeter. I am already using influxdbbackendlistener but unable to get tree result in influxdb.

Comment: If your team needs to see result in view tree listener, no point running it in a Non-GUI mode.

Comment: @4m01 Is there a way we can ship view result tree results in Influxdb, if we can then easy to show in grafana?

Comment: InfluxDB is time-series db, it is used to store time series data. You can't store response directly to influxDB anyway. TBH I'm getting why your team needs view results tree? Ask the questions what is the intention ?

Comment: Use JMeter APDEX reporting with setting to save response on only failure. that way they can have aggregated view and also find out what the response when occurred. If you going to save every response it would be heavily resource consumable and considered as bad practice. If you are just testing API then it might make sense. But still in tha case you can use Mavnised-Jmeter and some plugin for required reporting

Comment: Thanks But as mentioned will it send the report to influx?